# Time from now until minute 0 of next hour

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I want a python script to determine how many minutes or seconds are left between now and the start of the next hour (aka the 0th minute of the next hour).  So if it is 1:02PM then the answer would be 58 minutes.

In my research I have only found ways to calculate from now until a single specific time, not a relative time as in this case.  I tried to extract the hour, increment it by one (unless its 11pm), zero out the minutes and seconds, then finally subtract the two datetimes from each other.  But this seems really roundabout and I figure there must be a better way

Comment: Did you tried something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datetime` module will work for this.

```py
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.now()
minutes = 59 - time.minute
secs = 59 - time.second
print(str(minutes)+" minutes and "+str(secs)+" seconds until the next hour")
```

Comment: That will output 60:60 at 00:00.

Comment: And now it's still a second off. You should check your code.

Comment: @KlausD. no, it will be `59:59`! Cause it's `59 - 00` and not `60 - 00`?

Comment: At 59:59 it is 1 second left, not 0.

Comment: Thanks Otterlord.  This is much better than anything I had in mind!

Comment: This problem will appear at the end of every hour? I think it will be better to use `secs = (59 - time.second) + 1`, if I'm not wrong!